# Symfony2 - Collection type is displayed twice in my view

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with a collection and I can see it properly when I use the following syntax:

```
form_row(form.items)
```

Then when I try to render it by myself, it is duplicated.

Here is my code in my twig file:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_start(form) }}

    ... some fields here ...

    <div id="{{ form.items.vars.id }}" class="collection items" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.items.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        <h3>{{ form_label(form.items) }}</h3>
        <a href="#" class="add_link">Add</a>
        {% for item in form.items %}
            {{ form_row(item) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    ... some other fields here ...

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Here is my code in my form object:

```
    $builder->add('items', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new ItemType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'required' => true,
    ));
```

Add here is my output:

```
<!-- This is the one I need, I removed the prototype for the sake of clarity -->
<div id="bundle_data_items" class="collection items" data-prototype="...">
    <h3>
        <label class="required">Items</label>
    </h3>
    <a href="#" class="add_link">Add</a>
</div>
<!-- This one is automatically added. The prototype is empty -->
<div>
    <label class="required">Items</label>
    <div id="bundle_data_items" data-prototype=""></div>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas why this happens?

I followed that [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). Did I miss something?

#### Edit:

This happens only when my collection is empty

Comment: So what are the contents of `... some fields here ...` and `... some other fields here ...`... are you outputting something twice by accident in the Twig file?

Comment: @sjagr I double checked and nothing else is outputted twice. The other fields are not collections and are displayed like ```{{ form_row(form.comment) }}```

Comment: Try `form_widget` instead and see if that works?

Comment: It works with ```form_widget```. The problem is that what is rendered is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to that.

It turns out that when the collection is empty, the rendering of it never occurs. I could use **sjagr** solution but as there is some fields I want to render automatically, I cannot use it.

So my solution is the following:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_start(form) }}

    ... some fields here ...

    <div id="{{ form.items.vars.id }}" class="collection items" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.items.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        <h3>{{ form_label(form.items) }}</h3>
        <a href="#" class="add_link">Add</a>
        {% for item in form.items %}
            {{ form_row(item) }}
        {% else %}
            {% do form.items.setRendered %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    ... some other fields here ...

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

When your collection is empty, the `for` loop in `{% for item in form.items %}` never gets to execute, hence `form_row(item)` never happens. This means, to Twig/Symfony, you never actually outputted the field.

Then you do `form_end` at the end of the form. This is not usually a big deal, but [from the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables):

> This helper also outputs `form_rest()` unless you set `render_rest` to false

So, you must simply pass a `false` value for `render_rest`:

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

I'm not sure how `form_widget` *did* fix your problem, but I'm also not sure how you tried that alternative - perhaps you ran it outside of the `for` loop.

As an aside, you should consider making your own `form.html.twig` template file so you can reuse the markup format you've chosen for your collection. It will allow you to simply do `form_widget(...)` without having to break apart the pieces and your `form_end` will always consider the field to be outputted even if the collection is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I didn't know about the ```form_end``` options. I keep in mind to make my own widgets in the future.

Comment: @A.D. No worries - [here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/sjagr/85a2d3779cff9b9827c2) of an example customization that I pulled from one of my projects for you. Of course there's lots of ways to do it, so my format is just one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the example. It will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i cannot comment yet (no 50 rep), but perhaps this is caused the browser itself.  A rendering issue due to markup someplace? See if the raw http response has the same thing.  Since it works with form_row(form.items) but not your own, it "could be" that.

I would check if it's empty also before outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me, label of CollectionType was rendering twice when Collection is empty, but it was rendering once when there are data.
This is my configuration:

```php
$builder->add('items', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => NumberType::class,
    'required' => true,
    'label' => 'Fields',
    'entry_options' => [
        'label' => false,
    ],
    'prototype' => true,
])
```

and in Twig I was displaying Collection label in this way:
`{{ form_label(form.items) }}` and rendering field widgets in somewhere else. In this case label was displayed twice, once where this code is placed, and the other at the end of form.

Solution is to change it to:
`{{ form_row(form.items) }}`

or if you need custom rendering for form widgets like in my case, following code will print only labels:

```
{% if 0 < (form.items|length) %}
    {{ form_label(form.items) }}
{% else %}
    {{ form_row(form.items) }}
{% endif %}
```